# Steps required NOT to support iphone3g

Tags: iphone, xcode5, retina-display, iphone-3gs

I have created a universal app for iphone. 
My questions is what are the steps necessary to NOT support iphone3g and non retina device. What are the settings in xCode and iTunes Connect that I need to adjust to pass review process?

Comment: For now I am going to go with setting deployment target high enough to exclude the devices. Will keep this question open until I get feedback from App Submission. Will post the results

Comment: Turns out development target is the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last iOS version that the iPhone 3G supported was 4.2.1.  If you set your "iOS Deployment Target" to a value above 4.2.1 (Example: 5.0), this would make it so the app would not run on those devices.  The iOS Deployment Target setting is located under the "Build Settings" tab.

Be aware that the iPhone 3GS is non-retina and would require a value higher than 6.1.3 to exclude it.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a long winded way of going about doing it when you could just click on `General` and `iOS Deployment Target` is right there so no need to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The iPad mini 1st gen is a non-retina device running iOS 7.x, so the development target won't help you.

If you would want to exclude the iPad mini as well, you could require a camera with flash via `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`, but that would:
a) exclude all iPad models with retina display as well
b) probably get your app rejected

So, while I share the wish to stop wasting development time and disk space for the sake of non-retina support, I'm afraid we're stuck with it for the time being.

Comment: `iPhone 3GS` is also none retina but this device supports all the way up to `iOS 6.1`  whilst the `iPhone 3G` only supports up to `iOS 4.2` so you could drop support for `iPhone 3G` by just changing the `Deployment target` to `iOS 5`